Al usar un dataclass y comparar un objeto == se invoca el metodo hashcode()?
Buscaba referencias pero no encuentro, en este
data class Persona(..)
val persona1 = Persona("Juan", 30)
val persona2 = Persona("Juan", 30)
if(persona1 == persona) ??

La pregunta es, si al llamar == , el hashcode se incluye en la comparacion, o no?

No. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/equality.html#structural-equality

Al comparar un objeto ==, NO se invoca el metodo hashcode(). Te sugiero revisar las documentaciones de https://kotlinlang.org/docs/equality.html y https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/hash-code.html

En lenguaje Kotlin, cuando se usa el operador == entre dos objetos, se llama internamente al método equals(), no se llama al método hashcode()
Aunque recuerda lo que indica la función hashcode():

hashcode(): Si dos objetos son iguales según el método equals(), entonces llamar al método hashcode() en cada uno de los dos objetos debe producir el mismo resultado entero.

De acuerdo a lo anterior, los métodos equals() y hashcode() están alineados para asegurar que objetos iguales  equals() tengan el mismo hashcode() .

asi es , lo investigue mas a fondo y de echo en donde si se llama es cuando lo estas usando con maps, aunque no recuerdo si con listas tambien.
